# Contacts table with multiple entries?

Tags: database-design, duplication, relations

Here is a part of our Database:

```
Table: Users
ID            INT
First Name    VARCHAR
Last Name     VARCHAR
Email Address VARCHAR
...

Table: Contacts
ID            INT
User_id       INT (Foreign Key)
First Name    VARCHAR
Last Name     VARCHAR
Email Address VARCHAR (Unique)
Phone Number  VARCHAR
Address       VARCHAR
...
```

A `user` can have multiple `contacts` (One-to-many relationship).

It is possible that a `contact` of one `user` is also a `contact` of another `user`. And the second user may try to enter different `phone number`/`address` (but same `email address`). I cannot allow duplicate email addresses.

One possible solution is to split contacts table into 2 tables:

```
Table: Contacts
ID            INT
Email Address VARCHAR
...

Table: Contact_attributess
ID            INT
User_id       INT (Foreign Key)
Contact_id    INT (Foreign Key)
First Name    VARCHAR
Last Name     VARCHAR
```

**Is this the best way to reorganize my DB? Do you have other solutions?**

Comment: Can a user have several email addresses (in your database)?

Answer (score 1):

```
user table
---------
USERID
EmailAddress

User Details
-------------
USerDetailID
USERID (FK)
FirstName
-----

USER_Contact_Mapping
--------------------
USERcontactMapID 
UserID
contactID
```

`User table` hold info of both User and contact.This table can by utilise to hold other 
info which won't be duplicated.

`User Details` table hold info of both User and contact.This table contain multiple detail of same user.
Example

`USER_Contact_Mapping` contain relation between USERID and ContactID.This table is must.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add 3 additional tables (2 of them are linking tables), so it will be:

1. Users
2. Users_Contacts (to address multiple users in a single contact)
3. EmailAddress (to address multiple users in a single email address)
4. Users_EmailAddress (to address multiple users in a single email address)
5. Contacts

On Users_Contacts table, it will the primary key of users and contacts table.
On Email Address table, unique email can still be enforced here.
On Users_EmailAddress table, it will the primary key of users and emailaddress table.

This way, you can have
    - multiple users on a single emailaddress, and
    - multiple users on a single contact

Also, you may want to remove first_name and last_name columns in contact table since information is already in users table.

Answer (score 0):

Our database has the in-between table called not "User_Contact_Mapping" but User2Contact", because we think that's cute - for the word "to", we used a numeral 2!  Also, it saves a few keystrokes.

Also, our "User" table has a "MainContact" column which holds a contact id.  This has good and bad consequences; think about whether you need something like that.  I think we've been regretting that decision for about 10 years.  Enforcing that every user has a contact and every contact has a user, without making it impossible to input any new records... is tricky.  Then a system user has the bright idea to type a new contact's details into an existing contact record...