# Modeling a database structure for contact management

Tags: mysql, database-design

I was wondering what was the best design I could make for reusability, long-term maintenance and scaling for my database design. I am currently the only programmer at my job and they need a good database for a future project. All the application will use is this database for local user login, for customer (which can be also a company) tracking etc.

The database management system I will use is MySQL.

Basically what I want to implement is a database that will keep track of all the users we have to eventually configure some [ATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_telephone_adapter) automatically. Furthermore, I need this database to contain customers as well as companies (which are customers also). I need this database to contain users, which are employees. I want to fusion both "databases", but I am not sure what is the proper way to do it.

**Business rules**

- A *Party* can have multiple *Email*
- A *Party* can have multiple *Phone*
- An *Employee* is a *Party*
- A *Customer* is a *Party*
- A *Company* has a *Party* as a *Contact*
- A *Company* can have multiple *Address*
- A *Customer* can have multiple *Address*
- A *Customer* can have multiple *ATA* (Not shown in my diagram)
- A *Company* can have multiple *ATA*
- There are exactly-three *PhoneTypes*: 'Home', 'Office' and 'Cellphone'
- A *Phone* can be of exactly one *PhoneType*

So a *Customer* is essentially a *Party* but it has *Address(es)* while an *Employee* is a *Party* who has restriction. I don't know how to fit *Company* in there. My current design has *Company* attached to *Customer* with a one-to-many relation(one customer, multiple companies).

In short I want to create a database that contain *Companies*, *Customers* and *Employees* login information (no *pay check* involved here). How can I optimize my (application program) UML schema to fit all those criteria?

**Additional information**

Here is how my new design works, I am still not sure of the *Company* integration in my schema:

[image: Schema 2]

I thought that *Company* and *Customer* are quite the same so I made them both *Customer*. Perhaps adding a column for ­`IS_COMPANY` could do the trick?

**Responses to comments**

> What can be phone type? How many phone types can exist? Since there can be multiple emails, phones and addresses, why not keep them in one table called `contact`. [Here's a small version of your problem](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/174629/contacts-table-with-multiple-entries/174633#174633). - *KumarHash*

Phone type has three possibilities: "Home", "office" or "cellphone". I made it that way so I can load my dropdown values from the relevant table. `Party` is the `contact` table you mentionned; I coukd have named it like that, but I chose "party" after I read another question on SO.